# PHP - ftp_close(): SSL_read on shutdown

Tags: php

I have problem with ftp_close() function. I established connection over ftp_ssl_connect:

`$connection = ftp_ssl_connect('host', 21, 100);`

Download some files and everything is ok. But when I tried to close the connection by

`ftp_close($connection);`

I got error `ftp_close(): SSL_read on shutdown`. I tried to google it, but without no success.

The funny thing is, that everything is running in docker and error appears only in production environment which is totaly same and running on AWS.

Comment: This bug still exists in PHP7.4.1

Answer (score 3):

Resolved!
It's a problem of PHP 7.2.
I posted a bug report here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=77151

Thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting before logging like thus:

```
$ftp_conn = ftp_ssl_connect(YOUR_SERVER);

$ftp_login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, YOUR_USERNAME, YOUR_PASSWORD);

ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you check your connection variable after connecting, try debugging by print_r and var_dump, it will help you to understand the issue, may be some other function or variable modifying  **$connection**

> bool ftp_close ( resource $ftp_stream ) Returns TRUE on success or
>   FALSE on failure.
>
> ftp_close() closes the given link identifier and releases the
>   resource.

```
<?php

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// print the current directory
echo ftp_pwd($conn_id); // /

// close this connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: It does return this in production server /PHP Warning:  ftp_close(): SSL_read on shutdown: Success (0)

Comment: Try to close ssl connection first and then close ftp connection.

 SSL_shutdown() shuts down an active TLS/SSL connection. It sends the "close notify"  shutdown alert to the peer. 

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_shutdown.html